# Pandas: Swapping cells in excel

Tags: excel, pandas

I have data in excel (3 columns)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KLM: 123 | QRS: 345 | NOP: 356 |
| NOP: 454 | KLM: 123 | QRS: 564 |
| NOP: 65 | KLM: 423 | QRS: 642 |
| QRS: 54 | KLM: 523 | NOP: 325 |
| QRS: 234 | KLM: 123 | NOP: 56 |
| KLM: 234 | NOP: 5425 | QRS: 3425 |

I am trying to swap the value and get the results shown below. i.e. values starting with "KLM" in one column, "QRS" in second column, followed by "NOP" in third column.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KLM: 123 | QRS: 345 | NOP: 356 |
| KLM: 123 | QRS: 564 | NOP: 454 |
| KLM: 423 | QRS: 642 | NOP: 65 |
| KLM: 523 | QRS: 54 | NOP: 325 |
| KLM: 123 | QRS: 234 | NOP: 56 |
| KLM: 234 | QRS: 3425 | NOP: 5425 |

any help using pandas or excel would be appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @SubhaanKhan , can you try my solution and let me know if it works for you please

Answer (score 3):

Do with `np.sort` then pass to dataframe

```
import numpy as np 
out = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values)).iloc[:,[0,2,1]]
Out[346]: 
          0          2          1
0  KLM: 123   QRS: 345   NOP: 356
1  KLM: 123   QRS: 564   NOP: 454
2  KLM: 423   QRS: 642    NOP: 65
3  KLM: 523    QRS: 54   NOP: 325
4  KLM: 123   QRS: 234    NOP: 56
5  KLM: 234  QRS: 3425  NOP: 5425
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it worked for the first 1066 rows , i.e., KLM, QRS, NOP
after few hundred rows are sorted as QRS, KLM, NOP
and then NOP, QRS, KLM
its strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting row wise

##### Creating data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['KLM: 123', 'NOP: 454', 'NOP: 65', 'QRS: 54', 'QRS: 234', 'KLM: 234'],
                   'B': ['QRS: 345', 'KLM: 123', 'KLM: 423', 'KLM: 523', 'KLM: 123', 'NOP: 5425'],
                   'C': ['NOP: 356', 'QRS: 564', 'QRS: 642', 'NOP: 325', 'NOP: 56', 'QRS: 3425']},
                  )
```

##### Sorting

```
df.values.sort()
```

##### Output:

This gives us the expected results :

```
df
          A          B          C
0  KLM: 123   NOP: 356   QRS: 345
1  KLM: 123   NOP: 454   QRS: 564
2  KLM: 423   NOP: 65    QRS: 642
3  KLM: 523   NOP: 325   QRS: 54
4  KLM: 123   NOP: 56    QRS: 234
5  KLM: 234   NOP: 5425  QRS: 3425
```